# Create sql statement using sql query

Tags: mysql

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
'UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL_DATE = '||a.col_date||', COL_ID = '''||a.col_id||'''
WHERE COL_VAR = '''||a.col_var||''';' AS sql_query
FROM
(SELECT t2.COL_VAR AS col_var, t2.COL_DATE AS col_date, t3.COL_ID AS col_id                           
FROM TABLE2 t2 JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t2.col_var = t3.col_var) a;
```

the output I am aiming for is something like this

> UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL_DATE = DATE1, COL_ID = 'ID1' WHERE COL_VAR = 'VAR1';
>   UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL_DATE = DATE2, COL_ID = 'ID2' WHERE COL_VAR = 'VAR2';

*It works in oracle but not in mySQL... Is this possible in mySQL?*

Comment: CAN you add sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below..

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL_DATE = ''',
            t2.COL_DATE,
            ''', COL_ID = ''',
            t3.COL_ID,
            ''' WHERE COL_VAR = ''',
            t2.COL_VAR,
            '''')
FROM
    TABLE2 t2
        JOIN
    TABLE3 t3 ON t2.col_var = t3.col_va;
```